# How to change sub-theme of zen to find files in other folders?

Tags: drupal, drupal-themes

Im using Zen as my base theme for creating custom themes in Drupal 6.

When I look at the source code of my sub-theme, I see that zen are searching for css files in the sub-theme's folder, at the current state it looks for its css files in :

/themes/zen/elementals/css/

how do I tell it to just search in /css folder ?

thanks!

Answer (score 0):

1. Look at theme-settings.php file of zen theme.
2. Try to implement THEMEHOOK_settings() function in your own template.php