# How to change sub-theme of zen to find files in other folders?

Tags: drupal, drupal-theming

Im using Zen as my base theme for creating custom themes in Drupal 6.

When I look at the source code of my sub-theme, I see that zen are searching for css files in the sub-theme's folder, at the current state it looks for its css files in :

/themes/zen/elementals/css/

how do I tell it to just search in /css folder ?

thanks!

Comment: No need to post the same question with another account, you won't get more answer
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5334048/how-to-change-sub-theme-of-zen-to-find-files-in-other-folders

Answer (score 1):

With most themes (and subthemes, I believe) you can specify the location of the css file in the theme's .info file.

Comment: you cannot specify the css location to point to the root_folder/css/file.css

Comment: I guess I don't understand why you need to use the css file in that location - or failing that, why you couldn't copy it to the subtheme's default location? Did you specify the location (with full path) in the .info file?